# pandas find similar row in a column, make a new column according to the condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df,
query    subject    HPSame
0  WP_77.1  WP_706.1   HPS_1
1  WP_78.1   WP_46.1   HPS_2
2  WP_57.1   WP_26.1   HPS_3
3  WP_57.1  WP_627.1   HPS_4
4  WP_15.1   WP_16.1   HPS_5
5  WP_15.1   WP_17.1   HPS_6
6  WP_15.1   WP_63.1   HPS_7
7  WP_15.1   WP_61.1   HPS_8
8  WP_15.1   WP_56.1   HPS_9
9  WP_40.1   WP_11.1  HPS_10

I tried,

```
df['query_s'] = df['query'].shift(-1)
df['HPSame_s'] = df['HPSame'].shift(-1)
condition = [(df['query'] == df['query_s'])]
ifTrue = df['HPSame']
ifFalse = df['HPSame_s']
df['match'] = np.where(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse)
```

This throws me ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

I also tried, the following but does not give me my intended result.

```
df.loc[(df['query'] == df['query_s']), 'match'] = df['HPSame']
df.loc[(df['query'] != df['query_s']), 'match'] = df['HPSame_s']
```

I am looking for resuts as,
df =
query   subject  HPSame   match
0  WP_77.1  WP_706.1   HPS_1   HPS_1
1  WP_78.1   WP_46.1   HPS_2   HPS_2
2  WP_57.1   WP_26.1   HPS_3   HPS_3
3  WP_57.1  WP_627.1   HPS_4   HPS_3
4  WP_15.1   WP_16.1   HPS_5   HPS_5
5  WP_15.1   WP_17.1   HPS_6   HPS_5
6  WP_15.1   WP_63.1   HPS_7   HPS_5
7  WP_15.1   WP_61.1   HPS_8   HPS_5
8  WP_15.1   WP_56.1   HPS_9   HPS_5
9  WP_40.1   WP_11.1  HPS_10  HPS_10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(pandas) Create new column based on first element in groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613885/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-first-element-in-groupby-object)

Comment: Not really. My question is bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ffill`:

```
df['match'] = df['HPSame'].where(df['query'] != df['query'].shift()).ffill()
```

Output:

```
     query   subject  HPSame   match
0  WP_77.1  WP_706.1   HPS_1   HPS_1
1  WP_78.1   WP_46.1   HPS_2   HPS_2
2  WP_57.1   WP_26.1   HPS_3   HPS_3
3  WP_57.1  WP_627.1   HPS_4   HPS_3
4  WP_15.1   WP_16.1   HPS_5   HPS_5
5  WP_15.1   WP_17.1   HPS_6   HPS_5
6  WP_15.1   WP_63.1   HPS_7   HPS_5
7  WP_15.1   WP_61.1   HPS_8   HPS_5
8  WP_15.1   WP_56.1   HPS_9   HPS_5
9  WP_40.1   WP_11.1  HPS_10  HPS_10
```

Comment: Hi Quang, I apologize for not making my question clear. Your solution is absolutely correct the way I asked my question. What I essentially trying to achieve is that 'query WP_15' is the same as 'subject WP_16, WP_17, WP_63, WP_61, WP_56', so they all should have the same name HPS_5. Also, downstream this df, WP_16 or any in this set may be a query and may have multiple same subject as WP_224, WP_500, etc etc, which all should also have the same name HPS_5. Would you be able to give a solution this way or should I re-edit the question. Thank you for your time. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `groupby.transform('first')` as in

```
df['match'] = (
    df.groupby('query')['HPSame'].transform('first')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output

```
     query   subject  HPSame   match
0  WP_77.1  WP_706.1   HPS_1   HPS_1
1  WP_78.1   WP_46.1   HPS_2   HPS_2
2  WP_57.1   WP_26.1   HPS_3   HPS_3
3  WP_57.1  WP_627.1   HPS_4   HPS_3
4  WP_15.1   WP_16.1   HPS_5   HPS_5
5  WP_15.1   WP_17.1   HPS_6   HPS_5
6  WP_15.1   WP_63.1   HPS_7   HPS_5
7  WP_15.1   WP_61.1   HPS_8   HPS_5
8  WP_15.1   WP_56.1   HPS_9   HPS_5
9  WP_40.1   WP_11.1  HPS_10  HPS_10
```