# (pandas) Create new column based on the presence or not of an element in groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a problem that is close to this one :

[(pandas) Create new column based on first element in groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613885/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-first-element-in-groupby-object)

So I have this dataframe:

```
     accidentID      cartype   
0    58              70     
1    58              -70      
2    58              70     
3    58              100       
4    71              100   
5    71              -70    
6    250             70   
7    250             70  
8    250             100  
9    250             70  
10   70              70
```

What I want is to add a new column to show the car_in_the_wrong for a given accidentID knowing that :

if a cartype = -70 is present --> car_in_the_wrong = -70

if a cartype = 100 is present and no cartype = -70 --> car_in_the_wrong = 100

if 100 and -70 absent --> car_in_the_wrong = 70

```
     accidentID      cartype        car_in_the_wrong
0    58              70             -70
1    58              -70            -70
2    58              70             -70
3    58              100            -70
4    71              100            -70
5    71              -70            -70
6    250             70             100
7    250             70             100
8    250             100            100
9    250             70             100
10   300             70             70
```

Is there a way to do it with a groupby?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry indeed it didn't match. Now I hope it is clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this answer on how to [Check if a value exists using multiple conditions within group in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680467/check-if-a-value-exists-using-multiple-conditions-within-group-in-pandas), and taking advantage that statements with `or` are evaluated from left to right (i.e. the right-side part is not evaluated if the left-side holds True):

```
df['car_in_the_wrong'] = df['accidentID'].map(df.groupby('accidentID').apply(lambda x: x['cartype'].eq(-70).any()*-70 or x['cartype'].eq(100).any()*100 or x['cartype'].eq(70).any()*70))
```